# conversão hex to string oracle

Tags: oracle

Criei a seguinte consulta e ao executar é exibida uma mensagem de erro. Alguém tem uma ideia do que poderia ser?

Consulta:

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW(relatorio)) FROM GRELBATCH 
where IDJOBLOG = (SELECT MAX(IDJOBLOG) FROM GRELBATCH);
```

Mensagem de erro:

> ORA-00997: uso inválido do tipo de dados LONG

Comment: a coluna relatorio é do tipo LONG RAW

Comment: O tipo LONG tem algumas restrições. Veja aqui.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116396/workaround-for-ora-00997-illegal-use-of-long-datatype